# tig configuration : set on tigrc --all as default

Tags: git, tig

In my `tig` configuration I usually use the command:

`tig --all`

How can I set this as the default in `~/.tigrc` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to your `~/.tigrc`:

```
set cmdline-args = --all
```

I got this from the tigrc documentation found in the tig project: https://github.com/jonas/tig/blob/master/doc/tigrc.5.adoc

Comment: `cmdline-args` is used internally by Tig and currently exposed, however, using it may randomly break other views. Will look into making it read-only.

Answer (score 13):

Any `git-log` flags you want to use by default for filtering commits shown ino the `main` view by default can be added to `main-options` in `~/.tigrc`:

```
set main-options = --exclude=refs/stash --all
```

Comment: Not works for me `tig warning: ~/.tigrc:1: Unknown option name: main-options`

Comment: You must be on an older version of tig. try using `cmdline-args` instead.